# Reference to browser-specific CSS?

Tags: css, webkit, opera, gecko

I'm looking for a reference for browser specific CSS. 
All the things that start with -moz, -webkit, -o, -khtml

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) for instance, the person answers with all the user-select 
codes for all the browser, but how did he know that Opera has that option? 
I couldn't find documentation for those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this link:

http://css3generator.com/

#### UPDATE

Here i found one more intresting website which may help u:

[**CSS PREFIXER**](http://cssprefixer.appspot.com/)

It automatically generates all browser compatible codes.

### MORE References:

#### [MOZILLA CSS EXTENSION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css_reference/mozilla_extensions)

#### [WEBKIT CSS EXTENSION](http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit.php)

#### [CSS SELECTOR TEST](http://www.css3.info/selectors-test/)

#### [OPERA CSS LIST](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera9/css/)

Comment: that's interesting, however it is still not a Reference.

Answer (score 1):

[CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/) has a searchable list of new features, along with which browsers support them. It's not a definitive reference, but it is a fairly comprehensive list of features, and it does specify which versions use vendor prefixes for each feature.

A more definitive list can be found per browser, within the browser itself. If you open the debugging tool within the browser (eg Firebug, or Chrome's Developer Tools window, etc), you will be able to navigate all the available styles, which will show you at a glance which ones require vendor prefixes.

The way to do it would vary between browsers, but I'd recommend browsing the DOM tree, because each element has a `style` node, which you can expand to reveal a full list of available styles.

Answer (score 0):

this article will answer you questions.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific

Ps. it's not browser specific but vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

Official doc from Opera: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/css/o-vendor/

(Presto 2.8 is current version of Opera's rendering engine. If you browse that documentation site you will find docs for other versions.)